# How to disable Viber icon in top menu bar on Mac OS

Tags: macos, terminal, menu-bar

Viber 12.8.1 on Mac OS has no option to turn off the icon in the top menu. How this icon can be disabled using the terminal?
I got rid of the Skype icon in the top menu with the following command:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i '' -e "s/this._tray =/\\/\\/is._tray =/" -e "s/this._trayBaseToolTip =/return;\\/\\/yBaseToolTip =/" /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar
```

There may be a way for Viber to do that.

Comment: Do you need a command to modify the app or are you OK with the traditional options like BarTender tool or option dragging the icon from the menu bar?

Comment: Is there an option to turn of the icon in the Menu Bar in Viber Preferences?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to hide the icon is using [Dozer](https://github.com/Mortennn/Dozer). Not the best way, but it allows hiding other icons too (for example Docker in my case).